# Nginx unable to get request from React Native app over internet

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, nginx

I have spring boot BE running on port 8080 on my server with nginx and ssl cert.
I have forwarded ports on my router 80 and 443 to the server.
Also i have ddns in no-ip.
This all works correctly.

Now i started developing mobile app with React Native and Expo. When I try to call some endpoint on my BE it works correctly when I open it in web browser. After I try to open it in physical device, only network error is printed.
For example Im trying to show this image: https://prieskumnici-is.ddns.net/api/img/bg/default/day.jpg
or call this endpoint: https://prieskumnici-is.ddns.net/api/api/background

when i load the image in emulator locally it also works (http://192.168.1.35:8080/...)

the endpoints are correct as im using them in my angular webpage

So I assume the problem is in nginx or Spring boot configuration
Also there are no logs in nginx nor Interceptor in BE gets any request

There are som codes:

nginx config

```
http {
  client_max_body_size 500M;

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name prieskumnici-is.ddns.net localhost;

    ssl_certificate C:/nginx/ssl/prieskumnici-is.crt;  # Path to your SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate_key C:/nginx/ssl/prieskumnici-is.key;  # Path to your SSL private key

    large_client_header_buffers 4 8096k;

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; 
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
      root "C:\Users\Singi\Desktop\prieskumnici\prieskumnici-ui\dist\prieskumnici-ui";
    index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    types {
      text/html                                        html htm shtml;
      text/css                                         css scss;
      text/xml                                         xml;
      image/gif                                        gif;
      image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
      application/javascript                           js mjs;
      application/atom+xml                             atom;
      application/rss+xml                              rss;
    }
  }
}
```

RN

```
return <ImageBackground source={{uri: "https://prieskumnici-is.ddns.net/api/img/bg/default/day.jpg"}} resizeMode="cover" style={{height: '100%'}}>
          <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Home</Text>
          </View>
       </ImageBackground>
```

I dont know what is relevant from Spring Boot for this issue

To summarize: API and nginx wont recieve request from Physical device with React Native app over internet

I tried to load any other API on the device and it works correctly, also tried to load image from other page and works fine: https://www.prieskumnici.sk/assets/img/banner_zbor.png

**UPDATE** I have configured the nginx to also proxy port 80 to the BE and it works, now i can show image like this:
http://prieskumnici-is.ddns.net/api/img/bg/default/day.jpg
from emulator, but not from physical device

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
So I figured this finally, check your SSL cert, really :D
I was using .crt insted of .pem, also no-ip provides PEM and PEM chain, be sure to use PEM chain
this article helped: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16451#issuecomment-1937490176